# Every second in my log: "md5: BUG in libdispatch ..."

Tags: macos, console

I checked my log yesterday for an issue not related to this one and saw that aprox. every second I get a message like this:

```
Sep  6 10:54:32 my-mac.local md5[2257]: BUG in libdispatch: 12E55 - 1879 - 0x1b
Sep  6 10:54:32 my-mac.local md5[2258]: BUG in libdispatch: 12E55 - 1879 - 0x1b
Sep  6 10:54:33 my-mac.local md5[2259]: BUG in libdispatch: 12E55 - 1879 - 0x1b
Sep  6 10:54:33 my-mac.local md5[2260]: BUG in libdispatch: 12E55 - 1879 - 0x1b
Sep  6 10:54:34 my-mac.local md5[2262]: BUG in libdispatch: 12E55 - 1879 - 0x1b
```

Does anyone know what it is? Less advanced forums have proposed re-installing my Mac but that seems a bit too radical to me.

Comment: I'm seeing it too. How strange... "9/21/13 7:14:20.873 PM md5[18898]: BUG in libdispatch: 12F37 - 1879 - 0x1b"

Comment: I hava a hunch that it's Google Drive causing the problem.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Was it Google Drive related?  What made you suspect it was Google Drive related in the first place?

Comment: I don't have Google Drive installed and still get this error message spammed twice every second to my console. I therefore doubt very seriously that this has anything to do with Google Drive.

Answer (score 1):

What's interesting is that the md5 process is getting spawned quite rapidly. You can tell that by the incrementing process id (pid) - 2257, 2258, 2259, 2260

Can you run `top -u -s15` and see if you can determine the parent process of the md5?

From there, we can know what process is launching the chatty md5. Also, run a md5 process by hand `md5 /dev/null` to see if any error conditions are spit out other than the expected hash shown below:

```
Mac:~ me$ md5 /dev/null
MD5 (/dev/null) = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

Also, list any file synchronization tools you might have running - rsync, carbon copy cloner, dropbox, box.net, or similar... They often use md5 to tell if a file has really changed and needs to be synchronized.